# setState working as intended during development, slow upon deployment

Tags: javascript, reactjs, serverless, vercel

I have an issue where I'm making api calls to the backend depending on the state value.
Note:
during development, I am using an express environment to do all the handling of input data from frontend, however upon deploying, am using a serverless function to handle the same data on vercel.

The issue is that, I have a dropdown menu and onChange() triggers a call to get data and display on screen. Works perfect in the development server however once I deploy it, the API call fires before setState() changes the value of the state. I know this is the issue because when I change value again it brings the data from the previous value.

I am aware that useState() occurs asynchronously but why in the ****** is useState() changing values immediately in dev but not on deploy?? Is there a gotcha somewhere?

```
<TextField
 value = {someInvoice.input}
 onChange= {(e)=> {
   if (e.target.value === products[0]) {
    fireApiCall(e.target.value);
     setDataOnScreen({
                 ...dataOnScreen, price: {dataFromApiCall})}
    
   else if (e.target.value === products[1]) {
    fireApiCall(e.target.value);
     setDataOnScreen({
                 ...dataOnScreen, price: {dataFromApiCall})
      }
/>
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code. Please may you add a [mcve]?

Comment: You can put console logs in if statements and see where exactly the code is running slow and then find out that exact problem .